# How to write a CASE statement in the WHERE clause in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to rewrite a piece of SQL code that was initially written for Vertica. Vertica has the `AGE_IN_YEARS()` built-in function which was great to get someone's age. But, now, I need to find a way to have it to work in Snowflake and I did.

An equivalent statement that replaces `AGE_IN_YEARS(DateOfBirth)` in Snowflake can be:

```
case when dateadd(year, datediff(years, DateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE), DateOfBirth) > CURRENT_DATE
then datediff(years, DateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE) -1
else datediff(years, DateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE)
end as AGE
```

The issue is when I have to use this in a WHERE clause. The original Vertica code is:

```
SELECT name, dob,
(SELECT AgeRangeCode
   FROM AgeRangeTable
   WHERE AGE_IN_YEARS(DateOfBirth) BETWEEN MinAge AND MaxAge) AS AgeRangeCode,
CURRENT_DATE as TODAY
from MemberInfoTable
```

and if i add the `AGE_IN_YEARS()` replacement to the above query, I get

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

How do I go about writing this case in the WHERE clause

Comment: `CASE` is provided in SQL to allow Boolean evaluation where it is not normally allowed. The `WHERE` clause is specifically for making Boolean evaluations, so using `CASE` within the `WHERE` clause is usually a misstep.

Comment: Maybe it can't tell that that's going to be a scalar result. You can easily change that to an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is when I have to use this in a WHERE clause.

How about adding the age to the `dateofbirth` instead?

```
where dateadd(year, minage, dateofbirth) <= current_date and
      dateadd(year, maxage + 1, dateofbirth) > current_date
```

Comment: Still getting "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"

Comment: @ElDj . . . There is no subquery in this answer.  It addresses the question of how to do the age comparison in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

not using a function to calculate age, just joining to the data you have like so works:

```
with age_range_table as (
    select * from values (0,16, 'A'),(16,18, 'B'),(18,1000, 'C') v(min_age, max_age, age_range_code)
), member_info_table as (
    select name, dob::date as dob from values ('user_80s', '1980-01-01'),('user_90s', '1990-01-01'),('user_10s', '2010-01-01') v(name, dob)
)
select m.name,
    m.dob,
    a.age_range_code
from member_info_table AS m
join age_range_table AS a
    ON m.dob < dateadd('years',-a.min_age, current_date)
    AND m.dob >= dateadd('years',-a.max_age, current_date);
```

giving:

```
NAME    DOB AGE_RANGE_CODE
user_80s    1980-01-01  C
user_90s    1990-01-01  C
user_10s    2010-01-01  A
```

but that is slightly gross to be doing function calls in a WHERE clause..

```
with age_range_table as (
    select * 
    from values 
        (0,16, 'A'),
        (16,18, 'B'),
        (18,1000, 'C') 
        v(min_age, max_age, age_range_code)
), member_info_table as (
    select name, dob::date as dob 
    from values 
       ('user_80s', '1980-01-01'),
       ('user_90s', '1990-01-01'),
       ('user_10s', '2010-01-01')
       v(name, dob)
), today_age_range_table as (
    select age_range_code
        ,dateadd('years',-min_age, current_date) as range_end_date
        ,dateadd('years',-max_age, current_date) as range_start_date
    from age_range_table
)
select m.name,
    m.dob,
    a.age_range_code
from member_info_table AS m
join today_age_range_table AS a
    ON m.dob < a.range_end_date
    AND m.dob >= a.range_start_date;
```

credit note: this is the same solution as Gordon's but with it explicitly shown. And the range logic changed to alter the range times once in a CTE verse altering user.dob for all rows. Based on the assumption you have more users than ranges, and if both are sub 1000 you have no problems ether.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Age column in your agerange table and you want to compare each customer/participant age with that and also in the min and max range of the age range table then you can simply do it in 2 ways.

```
SELECT name, dob,
       [AgeRangeCode] = (SELECT AgeRangeCode FROM AgeRangeTable WHERE DATEDIFF(Year,mi.dob,CURRENT_DATE) = mi.age 
                                                         AND DATEDIFF(Year,mi.dob,CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN MinAge AND MaxAge),
       CURRENT_DATE as TODAY
from MemberInfoTable mi
```

or with a simple join like below

```
SELECT mi.name, mi.dob, art.AgeRangeCode,
       CURRENT_DATE as TODAY
FROM  MemberInfoTable mi
JOIN  AgeRangeTable art ON art.age = DATEDIFF(Year,mi.dob,CURRENT_DATE)
WHERE DATEDIFF(Year,mi.dob,CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN art.MinAge AND art.MaxAge
```